# Error with Ghostscript when using ImageMagick

Tags: vb.net, pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

I'm developing a web app, and right now I'm attempting to convert a PDF file into a PNG image by using ImageMagick and Ghostscript. I downloaded the following file: [Magick.NET-7.0.0.0007-Q16-x86-net20.zip], unzipped its files and placed then in the bin folder of my Visual Studio project. I also installed Ghostscript 9.15 for Windows (32 bit). Then I tried to convert a PDF file that I had previously created, as a test, by using the example for VB.Net in the ImageMagick documentation:

```
Dim settings As New MagickReadSettings()
' Settings the density to 300 dpi will create an image with a better quality
settings.Density = New MagickGeometry(300, 300)

Using images As New MagickImageCollection()
  ' Add all the pages of the pdf file to the collection
  images.Read("C:\MyProject\PDF\MY_PDF.PDF", settings)

  ' Create new image that appends all the pages horizontally
  Using horizontal As MagickImage = images.AppendHorizontally()
    ' Save result as a png
    horizontal.Write("C:\MyProject\PDF\MY_PDF.horizontal.png")
  End Using

  ' Create new image that appends all the pages horizontally
  Using vertical As MagickImage = images.AppendVertically()
    ' Save result as a png
    vertical.Write("C:\MyProject\PDF\MY_PDF.vertical.png")
  End Using
End Using
```

I ran my project to test the code, and I got this error:

```
ImageMagick.MagickDelegateErrorException: w3wp.exe: PDFDelegateFailed `[ghostscript library]
-q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 
-dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 
-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r300x300"  "-sOutputFile=C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/magick-
3224bC6h8EQ360KA%d" "-fC:/WINDOWS/TEMP/magick-3224IW9rcxT1iXj2" "-fC:/WINDOWS
/TEMP/magick-3224ROCAzr6PEGFK": (null)' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/772
```

(The error occurs in this line):

```
images.Read("C:\MyProject\PDF\MY_PDF.PDF", settings)
```

Does anyone understand what's wrong? Something I missed? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try running the same command from the shell, that way you will be able to see the Ghostscript stdout and stderr which may well give you more information.

Comment: I do not think any *Magick software with version number 7 could yet be regarded as stable. AFAIK, a ImageMagick release of version 7 is schedulded for 1st quarter of 2016 (not 2015!). So I'd advice you to try it with the most recent 6.8.9-10 (released, stable) version first.

Comment: Magick.NET no longer uses ImageMagick 6, it switched to IM7 this year so you cannot use 6.8.9-10. Can you add a link to the PDF file that is causing the problem or does it happen with every file. Feel free to also start a topic here: https://magick.codeplex.com/discussions.